# AngularJS how to invoke the ng-show on a div from another controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to AngularJS and trying to use it on an enterprise project. 
I have scaled many hurdles so far, but everyday with its issue!
Please, I need your help on this.

The functionality on this screen is a 2 step process.
When the page is first loaded the div1 is displayed and populated.
But, div2 is displayed with only a button.

Then, when the user clicks on the button in div2, div2 is populated by info from server.
So, we end up with div1 and div2 on the screen.
The 2 divs have unique angularjs controllers.

My problem is how to show and hide the div2, when user clicks on the link (toggleDiv2) within div1.

The show/hide is required to restart the processing i.e. clicking the the link (toggleDiv2)  repopulates div1 with new set of html controls for a new web service call to populate div2.
I have tried simplifying the scenario.

I have used the services for sharing data between controller and done show/hide within same controller. 
But, this one is show/hide between multiple controllers, it beats me o!
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
<div id="div1" ng-controller="EventSourceCtrl">

         <a id="toggleDiv2" href="#" ng-  click="functionDefinedInEventDestinationCtrl('false');"> Close Div named myDiv </a>

</div>

<div id="div2" ng-show="someFlagOrFunctionInaControllerOrService" ng-controller="EventDestinationCtrl">

    <button id="buttonId" type="button" ng-click="getInfoFromServerToPopulateDiv2()" class="btn"></button>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm wondering why `functionDefinedInEventDestinationCtrl('false')` uses a string of `false` as its input?

Comment: I just made that up ... I will appreciate a snippet or logic of how to implement this .... I am not getting any AngularJS error ... Just cannot figure how to close a div residing in another controller. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set your flag to true from the `EventSourceCtrl`

```
// js

app = angular.module('app', [])

app.controller('EventSourceCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.functionDefinedInEventDestinationCtrl = function () {
    $scope.someNameSpace || ($scope.someNameSpace = {});
    $scope.someNameSpace.someFlagOrFunctionInaControllerOrService = true;
  }
});

// html

<div id="div2" ng-show="someNameSpace.someFlagOrFunctionInaControllerOrService" ng-controller="EventDestinationCtrl">
```

Comment: Thanks Gabe ... That did not work ...I guess its because the link is in a different controller as the div its trying to show/hide.

Comment: Ah yea. Please see my edits. Though `someFlatOrFunctionInaControllerOrService` is within the scope of the nested controller, the parent controllers are still able to manipulate it. That said, you need to namespace the variable so that it belongs to the parent controller. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTx23w4z6Kc